# Is it possible for a SQL update query to run partially?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, partial

I'm maintaining a website I developed a couple of months ago now and there is a query that sometimes runs partially (or something).

It updates an account level and deducts its cost from the account balance. The code which runs the query is the next:

```
$last = ( microtime(true) - 600) * 10000; // 10 minutes ago
$sql = "UPDATE users SET level = " . $new_level . ", last_claim = '$last', level_days_left = 30, balance = balance - $price WHERE id = $user_id LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

It usually works well but sometimes it doesn't :D
When it doesn't the balance remains equal and the rest of the fields are changed fine.

The first time I noticed this I thought the issue was that the amount contained in $price could be 0. As the price is calculated extracting it from the database I added some checks like stopping the execution if the price extraction is not successful or if the amount extracted is 0.

Some days after that it failed again so I added a function to debug all those queries when run. This is the last query which failed:

```
UPDATE users SET level = 2, last_claim = '14866845029652', level_days_left = 30, balance = balance - 1000000 WHERE id = 9706 LIMIT 1
```

**All the fields were changed except the balance.** Can this happen? Doesn't it return any error? In case of error, why doesn't it revert the changes? And finally... what is the best way to handle this situtations? Do I run another query right after this one to check if the changes where successful or is this inefficient?

**Some extra info:**

- The database is MySQL
- The site is written in PHP
- *balance* is an unsigned bigint
- yes, the code checks that the balance is enough to pay that price
- balances are not big enough to overflow the bigint max value

And yep, not much more :D

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to [SQL Injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Also, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would first of all checked whether the code checking the balance is in the same transaction as the updating request.

Comment: Also I don't recommend to use unsigned types to store money. In the case of error negative balance is much, much better then balance near to 9223372036854775807.